TwilioStudio - How to integrate my flow into an external platform?
I finally managed to finish my IVR. A question arose, is it possible to integrate my Twilio flow into a Service Center platform? I saw that there is the possibility of using Twilio Flex, however, since we already have a center, it would be interesting for the flow to receive the calls and then forward them to our center. Is there any possibility of doing this?

I think the Make Outgoing Call Widget might help you.

Good morning, I just discovered today that we don't have phone numbers assigned to our agents. Our center only has agents registered with defined skills. Is there a possibility to transfer the call from the customer to our platform, but without using a phone number?

Are you using Flex? Or can you share any details about how the routing to your agents works?

Forwarding a call with a Studio Flow is easy to do.  Here is an example...

Just add the connect call widget.  The key here is to use "{{contact.channel.address}}" in the Caller ID box so that the call appears to come from the original caller.
